# Can I post other ads than Google with adnsense

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Along with my google ads can I apply for other ad media and post their ads too with Google ads. I wanna post more ads. Is it allowed to use more than one adsense program and post both media's ads on same page?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but only if the other ads are non-contextual.

[There is a limit per page of AdSense units per page](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=9735), 3 banner units and 3 link units.

You may have any number of third party banners and links on the same page.

Comment: Sorry for my English but what does non-contextual mean? 
I am planning to put somewhat of a banner ad for a site that offers affiliate marketing, is that ok? Also text links for ebay (let's say I am reviewing a product and I have affiliate links to that product on a sale page) is that ok?